# create custom slug instead of id in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am fetching values from database and I have prepared the page link like www.test.com/wholesale/?id=NA%3D%3D as I have to fetch values on individual page but I wanted to have the name in link instead of encrypted id like www.test.com/plants/wholesale/rose.

Can any one help me in this that, is there any way that I can create custom links in wordpress. Is there any rewrite rule?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You can change the url using permalink settings https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Permalinks.
Select "Post Name" and then Save the changes.

Comment: these are not post or page , its just the data in database which I am fetching , so I feel it need custom work.

Comment: Are you displaying this data?

Comment: this I am fetching data and displaying my own whereas I wanted the link to be with name not with id

Comment: Are you displaying this data through a custom template or CPT or anything else?

Comment: Yes I have  created the template on which I have passed the id like ?id=NA%3D%3D ,  as encrypted id and with that I am fetching the data.

Comment: If I understood correctly what you're trying to say, this might help: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: I want like this for example : www.test.com/plants/wholesale/rose , where name of plant is going to change everywhere as some will be rose and some will be lilly and others some else , that is every link will have dynamic name.